# Scrapy: Store and process data

Tags: python, terminal, scrapy

> Hi everyone,
> I'm new to web scraping, and I am currently working on scraping Amazon for the price of something, in this case it's just an example (eco dot 3 because thats the first product I found).

I am confused about how to store the data though, as before I only ran the code from the terminal using the scrapy command `scrapy crawl Amazon -o amazon.json`. This runes the crawler "Amazon" and stores the output in the json file "amazon.json". I dont actually want to store the data in a file like this thought. What I want is to run the crawler when I run the actual python file. Would I have to create an instance of the Amazon spider? Or maybe somehow run the terminal command with os.system?

Anyway here's the code:

```
class AmazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Amazon"

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.amazon.de/Echo-Dot-3-Gen-Intelligenter-Lautsprecher-mit-Alexa-Sandstein-Stoff/dp/B07PDHSPXT/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3TC0DPYYXLIJW&dchild=1&keywords=echo+dot&qid=1594659298&sprefix=echo%2Caps%2C176&sr=8-1'
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for price in response.xpath("//td[@class='a-span12']"):       #the element in which the price resides
            yield {
                'price_text': price.xpath("//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']/text()").get()  
     #the element of the price tag
            }


#Thank you all in advance!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class AmazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Amazon"

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.amazon.de/Echo-Dot-3-Gen-Intelligenter-Lautsprecher-mit-Alexa-Sandstein-Stoff/dp/B07PDHSPXT/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3TC0DPYYXLIJW&dchild=1&keywords=echo+dot&qid=1594659298&sprefix=echo%2Caps%2C176&sr=8-1'
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for price in response.xpath("//td[@class='a-span12']"):       #the element in which the price resides
            yield {
                'price_text': price.xpath("//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']/text()").get()  
            }

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(AmazonSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: HI thanks for the answer! What exactly does the process function do? And where is the data stored? Thanks again!

Comment: Upvote and accept the answer if it has solved your question. @DanielRübenacker

Comment: Well Im still having the problem, that i dont know where to store the data or where the data is currently being stored, e.g. I cant use it to do other things.

Comment: You need to use ItemPipelines for that @DanielRübenackerhttps://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
But as far as the question is concerned the answer is correct I believe

Comment: Thank you!!! That's exactly what i've been looking for!